# Kotlin write a function that checks potentially dozens of values and returns their non-null values with lambda type

Tags: android, function, kotlin, null

So here is what I want to do: I have this set of nullable values:

```
 val orderDemand: String? = cell.orderDemand
 val orderNumber: Int? = cell.orderNumber
 val orderConceal: Boolean? = cell.orderConceal
 val scriptCode: String? = cell.scriptCode
 val scriptTimestamp: Long? = cell.scriptTimestamp
```

The thing is that sometimes they do come as null so I can't just initialise the values as Non-null.

I want to create a function or class that can work with potential dozens of values and should look like this:

```
 executeIfNotNull(
          cell.orderDemand,
          cell.articleImageURL,
          cell.articleTitle,
          cell.scriptCode,
          cell.scriptTimestamp){ orderDemand, orderNumber, orderConceal, scriptCode,
               scriptTimestamp ->
                   doSomethingWithAllTheseNonNullValues(...)
               }
```

I couldn't see any working solution on the internet for actual multiple values, but explicit solutions for 2 or max 3 values. I actually came across this solution for 6 values:

```
private fun <A,B,C,D,E,F,T> nonNullMultipleCheck(
    a:A, b:B, c:C, d:D, e:E, f:F, execute: (A, B, C, D, E, F) -> T) {
   if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null && d!=null && e!=null && f!=null) run {
       execute(a, b, c, d, e, f)
   }
}
```

I'm sorry but only a joke of a programmer would ever do that. I am looking for a solution where I can use Array or Set or Vararg where I can give all the nullable values as parameters and have access to the lambda result type by name (`{ orderDemand, orderNumber, orderConceal, scriptCode, scriptTimestamp ->`) just as I described in the function model above. How can I make this work with as many values as I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This cannot be solved in a type-safe way using vararg or collection because type parameters cannot be variadic. You can just create several overloads for different parameter count. But, honestly speaking, such number of nullables is a serious design flaw.

Comment: I totally agree with . @Miha_x64, even though I provided an answer.  As I said in the beginning of my answer, it's error-prone with a lot of assumptions. You might need to consider redesigning some part or just have different functions for different overloads as it will be easier and clearer to see the different execution points and the overall picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, to be honest I do not think that such method will solve your problem. Because if two arguments are of the same type,  how would you know which argument was null and which was not to execute your `doSomethingWithAllTheseNonNullValues()` method?

Nevertheless, here is a working example.

```
fun <T> executeWithoutNulls(vararg args: Any?, execute: (Array<Any>) -> T) {
    val filterArguments = args.toList().mapIndexed { index, any ->
        if (any != null) any
        else null
    }.filterNotNull()

    execute(filterArguments.toTypedArray())
}
```

You can pass as many characters as you like and then execute with as many not values as you find.

**Example:**

```
fun example() {
    val orderDemand: String? = "orderDemand"
    val orderNumber: Int? = null
    val orderConceal: Boolean? = true
    val scriptCode: String? = null
    val scriptTimestamp: Long? = 100L

    executeWithoutNulls(orderDemand, orderNumber, orderConceal, scriptCode, scriptTimestamp) {
        it.forEach {
            println("Example - value: ${it}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Example - value: orderDemand
Example - value: true
Example - value: 100
```

---

If you would like to preserve the order of the arguments, in order to know which one is which, then I would suggest the following modifications to the method.

```
fun <T> executeWithoutNullsIndexed(vararg args: Any?, execute: (Array<Pair<Int, Any>>) -> T) {
    val filterArguments = args.toList().mapIndexed { index, any ->
        if (any != null) Pair(index, any)
        else null
    }.filterNotNull()

    execute(filterArguments.toTypedArray())
}
```

**Example**

```
fun example() {
    val orderDemand: String? = "orderDemand"
    val orderNumber: Int? = null
    val orderConceal: Boolean? = true
    val scriptCode: String? = null
    val scriptTimestamp: Long? = 100L

    executeWithoutNullsIndexed(orderDemand, orderNumber, orderConceal, scriptCode, scriptTimestamp) {
        it.forEach {
            println("Example - Index: ${it.first} with value: ${it.second}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Example - Index: 0 with value: orderDemand
Example - Index: 2 with value: true
Example - Index: 4 with value: 100
```